# Dictionary based SMS encryption

Tags: encryption, dictionary, sms

I am trying to create end to end SMS encryption application, but don't want to use standard encryption algorithm.The idea is to convert the text of message to completely different meaningful text so that over the network it doesn't seem encrypted. I am assuming messages only in English language. 
In implementation part, I have first compressed the message using huffman encoding which gives me compressed stream of bits. Now for encryption I don't have any idea. Is it possible to build a dictionary of some random text or what other way can be used for getting such encryption? Decryption at other receiving end is also required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking for a a [codebook](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Codebook)? If you have access to an English language dictionary of 65536 entries for example, you can take every 16-bits of your message as an index into this table to get a word. Good luck converting this into a real cryptosystem.

Comment: Yes, I thought of using codebook initially. But using just words from respective indexes doesn't give much meaning to the sentence. And as I don't want to give it a look of encryption, I tried making a table of short English sentences. But then it exceeds the 160 char limit. And bitwise compression like huffman is not enough to avoid that. So instead of using direct sentences, I want some way of dynamically building sentences or para by using English words from codebook. I am totally confused how to do it. IS it possible?